# What are some of the philosophical implications if BPP = P?

Tags: complexity-theory, randomness, philosophy

As it stands, the general consensus seems to be that BPP = P. If this conjecture were indeed true, what would be some of the philosophical implications beyond theoretical computer science?

I know that the construction of my question is rather fuzzy. This is in the hopes of getting a diverse set of interpretations to yield interesting answers.

Comment: Consensus is a bit of a strong word, general opinion maybe!

Comment: I guess you're right. Calling it a "general opinion" would be the way to go. It's not fair to assume that most people agree that BPP = P is true.

Comment: You'd have to prove that [Polynomial identity testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_identity_testing) is in P...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.